# django admin many-to-many with intermediate model add new

Tags: python, django

I have the following models (simplified):

```py
class Concert(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    date = models.DateField()
    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song,
                                   through='RunOrder',
                                   related_name='run_order',
                                   blank=True)

class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class RunOrder(models.Model):
    concert = models.ForeignKey(Concert, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    act_no = models.SmallIntegerField()
    scene_no = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

Basically, songs can be in multiple concerts, concerts have multiple songs.

While creating a new concert in the admin view, I would like to be able to add new songs. Here's what I have:

```py
class ConcertAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = [SongInline]

class SongInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = RunOrder
    show_change_link = True
    extra = 1
```

But this only lets me select from existing songs. In order to add a new song, I have to use the Song admin interface. When I tried to use `Song` as the model for `SongInline`, I got a `has no ForeignKey` error. Is there a way I can streamline/inline the process of adding new Songs to a Concert?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is a default feature, but the admin interface has to be enabled for the Song model:

```
admin.site.register(Song)
```

Then you get the little plus sign. [Screenshot of django admin inline table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agvsg.png).